Problem book recomemendations for a math major freshman who's behind [algebra/precalculus/geometry]
I'm in a marginally specific position, and need recommendations for problem books related to algebra, precalculus or geometry (any or all), that cover more difficulties than basic to intermediate examples (for example, Stewart's Precalculus - which does a great job of teaching basic technique, but is lacking in problem variety/difficulty).
I went back to school at 27 prior to not having math classes in 10 years now. I've self-taught enough to get into a math program at a top 3 math program in my country, yet I am moderately behind top students. The areas I am lacking most in are algebra, precalculus and geometry, while I am surprisingly doing well with understanding the material at a conceptual level, such as analysis.
The difficulty I would describe is needed to help me would probably be hard high-school or something between high school and college, like a preparatory problem book. Solutions preferred, but not at all necessary. I simply lack intermediate and above material in general. It's difficult for me to find my footing in the more complicated problems that require more than reformulating a problem algebraically in one manner unto completion.
I unfortunately don't have the problem-solving chops to score highly on my tests, which is why I'm worried about my forthcoming exams. We are not provided problem books at uni, because we are expected to mostly work on our own.
I am very grateful for any guidance. I have checked the suggested similar topics and from what I can tell this is not a duplicate post.

I have a general trick for such questions (what I often do). For instance, I want to train my ability in geometry, then I open the geometry tag on MSE and sort them by score. Because in general, high-scoring questions are of high quality or most people have encountered this problem. Solving these problems can greatly improve your ability (and there are answers even if you don’t know how to do it). You can continue from the first page until you feel satisfied.

After finishing these questions, I usually review them again to see what tricks I used for the questions I couldn’t solve, and then classify these questions according to different tricks. Because the subjects you mentioned are not particularly difficult, when you can summarize some of the techniques used in the questions, not only will your level improve, but you will also encounter fewer and fewer difficult problems.

Thank you X K H, I will make sure to keep that method in mind. I believe I have found a resource that might be of good use, Openstax. Apparently these are free peer-reviewed textbooks with exercises. I reckon someone in a similar position might find this piece of advice helpful. I would love to receive recommendations, but if the rules necessitate the topic be closed now, I will oblige of course.

When I find that I am not familiar with a certain type of question, I will look for a large number of similar exercises on MSE to practice and summarize a set of tricks used. I can only say that this method is very useful to me. My scores in college are basically over 90 using this method.

Hit Schaum’s Outlines heavily and regularly.

I suggest you look up the Anneli Lax book series of the MAA New Mathematical Library, especially those covering several decades of the Erdos competition for high schoolers. The Moscow Mathematical Olympiads are published by the AMS. Both book series are excellent with extensive discussion of solutions and related topics.

Only answering this since I relate to this situation and here is what worked for me somewhat.
I will firstly suggest having some talk with the instructors if possible and get help/suggestions and more importantly working towards getting previous year problem sets.

Take a look at Khan Academy as well, a lot of the tricky & scholarship-style questions that appear in such exams are actually a few different "trivial" concepts intermixed with a hint of how much your brain can figure out the bounds and patterns.

For books, the two books which helped me immensely were:

Pure Mathematics Volumes 1 & 2 by S. L. Parsonson.
Core books in Advanced Mathematics from Macmillan. (Actually a series of tiny books, you can go through each in a single day).


If you are specifically looking for scholarship level problems however take a look at:

Test of mathematics at ten plus two level by East-West Press. (A gem I see the stats people often carrying!)
Past HMMT contest papers, freely available on the web.
For geometry, you didn't mention what style of questions but I would take a look at Solving Problems In Geometry by Hang & Wang (alternatively, https://ukmt.org.uk/product/new-problems-in-euclidean-geometry or https://ukmt.org.uk/product/plane-euclidean-geometry-theory-and-problems would be ideal) if you are dealing with euclidean things.
Series 0714 books from Springer.
For Algebra, Mir Publishers has some texts that have plenty of challenging material (go by searching Elementary Mathematics).

If you need even more challenging (but not olympiad level) book recommendation, just comment. I can probably list more.
Small tip: Start looking at bounds of any problems you encounter, looking at how big/small something gets and how something grows/shrinks or what the extreme values are reveals a tonne.
